# How can I inject dependencies to the Base class with Simple Injector?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

How can I register the `Rectangle` interface in a SimpleInjector container, at the same time `ILogger` is injected to it's base class `Shape` also?

The purpose of doing this is to make the derived class not concerned about the `ILogger`. The `ILogger` is an infrastructure service which is used to log some values to the file for debugging purpose.

```
public class Shape : IShape
{
    public void Shape(ILogger logger){}
    public virtual void Draw(){}
}

public class Rectanble : Shape
{
    public void Reactangular();
    public override void Draw(){}
}
```

Comment: This question in its current state is unclear. review and edit.

Comment: Why does shape need to log?

Comment: Are Rectangle and Shape the actual objects in your application to work with? These types of objects are quite unlikely to be built up using a DI Container.

Comment: The logger is to log some data in a file for logging purpose.

Comment: Dude :) I thik we get that the logger is for logging :). But why dhould a Shape do logging? That seems a Single Responsibility Principle violstion to me.

Comment: The Shape and Logger is a ```HAS-A``` relation. Its the D of SOLID.

Comment: That is correct, but that doesn't answer the question. Logging is a _cross-cutting concern_ so why should a geometrical shape do any logging at all?

Comment: An example: Shape has a draw method. The app will draw hundreds of shapes at various time. I want to log the attributes of any ```shape``` for debugging later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve this, you will have to expose logger through the constructor of the derived class:

```
public class Rectangle : Shape
{
    public Rectangle(ILogger logger) : base(logger) { }
    public override void Draw(){}
}
```

Do note that base classes that handle cross-cutting concerns like logging is a *strong indication* of violating the Single Responsibility Principle. These base classes easily become ever changing classes that contain lots of dependencies, making the derived classes harder to test and maintain.

Instead of having base classes with dependencies, it's usually much better to implement cross-cutting concerns using decorators. This keeps the base class clean and often even allows the removal of the base class altogether (or making it purely abstraction, or replace it with an interface).

Comment: Could you suggest any example for this? I have the same concern where I wanna expose a single class to all entities for internal use (a queue)